# SSH into raspberry pi

Tags: linux, ssh, remote-access

I have a question regarding SSH. For school assignments, I always write code on my mac then transfer it over on my raspberry pi to make sure it will compile correctly without errors as they are tested on the pi and sometimes when I transfer it has errors.

To avoid hassle of connecting everything to the pi, if I SSH into the pi, then compile my program from my mac, would it use the raspberry pi compiler?

Comment: `Cross compilation` is something that you want to look at. That way you can write code on your mac, compile it for ARM platform(raspberry pi).
If you are writing C code, have a look at this https://www.linux.com/blog/cross-compiling-arm

Comment: You can also avoid manually copying your code by using [version control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control) such as Git or Mercurial. You can then simply pull changes onto your Pi.

Answer (score 3):

If you are connected vi ssh and issuing the commands in that terminal session, yes, it's going to use the compiler on the pi.

A better option, and more educational, might be to cross-compile the code for the pi on your mac. You can leverage the much greater processing power of the desktop to significantly reduce your compile time.

[Cross Compiling on Mac OSX for Raspberry Pi](http://www.jaredwolff.com/blog/cross-compiling-on-mac-osx-for-raspberry-pi/)

Answer (score 2):

Yes it would remotely access the host's OS (in your case the RPi) to perform the compilation.

Here is a guide to get you started:
https://www.modmypi.com/blog/remotely-accessing-the-raspberry-pi-via-ssh-console-mode

**Also,** in case you want a remote desktop connection, on your raspberry pi enter the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install xrdp
```

providing you've already updated and upgraded your package libraries ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, If you are using ssh and writing code in that terminal session then the code will be compiled in the pi, it is the best way to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Issuing command in the terminal session via SSH (laptop connected with Raspi), compilation will be done at Raspi. PuTTY is a very useful tool for this, you just need to enable SSH at Raspi and input your IP address at PuTTY only! Click  to the PuTTY website http://www.putty.org/ and download it.

Answer (score 0):

Secure Shell (SSH) is a cryptographic network protocol for operating network services securely over an unsecured network. The best-known example application is for remote login to computer systems by users.

When you connect to any remote system or server via ssh you are using the same system via command prompt. So, if you do any work via SSH the compilation will be done by the remote system.